# Python regex pattern match starts with dot and store it in dict format

Tags: python, regex

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
from pprint import pprint

data = '''
. 
.
.
#Long log file
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Section Name                   | Budget    | Size      | Prev Size | Overflow
 --------------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------
  .text.resident                 |    712924 |    794576 |    832688 | YES
  .rodata.resident               |     77824 |     77560 |     21496 | YES
  .data.resident                 |     28672 |     28660 |     42308 | NO
  .bss.resident                  |     52672 |   1051632 |   1455728 | YES 
  
.
.
.
  
'''
```

**Output expected:**

```
MEMDICT = {'.text.resident' : {'Budget':'712924', 'Size':'794576', 'Prev Size': '832688' , 'Overflow': 'YES'},
           '.rodata.resident' : {'Budget':'', 'Size':'', 'Prev Size': '' , 'Overflow': 'YES'},
           '.data.resident' :{'Budget':'', 'Size':'', 'Prev Size': '' , 'Overflow': 'NO'},
           '.bss.resident' :{'Budget':'', 'Size':'', 'Prev Size': '' , 'Overflow': 'YES'}}
```

I am a beginer in python. Please suggest some simple steps

Logic:

- Search for a regex pattern and get the headers in a list

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\sSection Name\s|\sBudget*') # This can be improved, 
if(pattern.match(line)):
   key_list = (''.join(line.split())).split('|') # Unable to handle space issues, so trimmed and used.
```

- Search for a regex pattern to match .something.resident  | \d+ | \d+ | \d+ | **
  Need some help and get it in value_list
- Making all list into the dict in a loop

```
mem_info = {} # reset the list
for i in range(0,len(key_list)):
    mem_info[key_list[i]] = value_list[i]
    MEMDICT[sta_info[0]] = sta_info
```

Comment: You don't need regexes for this.  Read the file line by line.  Ignore lines until one contains `"Section Name"`.  Ignore lines with `'---------'`.  Now you can `.split` the line and have exactly the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you haven't shown us is what line ends the section.  Other than that, this is what you need:

```
keeper = False
memdict = {}
for line in open(file):
    if not keeper:
        if 'Section Name' in line:
            keeper = True
        continue
    if '-------------------' in line:
        continue
    if 'whatever ends the section' in line:
        break
    parts = line.split()
    memdict[parts[0]] = {
        'Budget': int(parts[1]),
        'Size': int(parts[2]),
        'Prev Size': int(parts[3]),
        'Overflow': parts[4]
    )
```

Comment: its a build log file, line ends with new line, There could be other matches also of  .resident or Section Name.
Need help to frame the regex to extract these line patterns to list,

Comment: What I was asking is, after you find the "Section Name" list and start gathering stats, how do you know when the section list is done?  What's the end signal?  And I'm telling you, don't need regexes for this.